# The method 'compareTo' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter

How to fix this? Error Message: The method 'compareTo' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').

[image]

Second Error: The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Object'.
How to fixed it?

[image]

Comment: it literally says in the message.

Comment: please, be sure to read this: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you lack basic understanding about null safety features.
`String?` basically means that it's a `String` that can be `null`. This can be done with any type. A question mark `?` at the end of the type name makes it nullable, and if it isn't there it can't be `null`.

The language is designed in such a way that you can't assign any objects that are nullable to variables that aren't or use methods of objects that might be null.

There are several ways to handle this.

**1) don't make them nullable in the first place.**

In your example, whatever the object is, it must have some field declared as `String? name`. Just remove the `?` if possible. There's a good chance it will make other errors pop up, but it should be solvable, at least in the case where you don't allow it to be `null`. If for whatever reason you need it to be nullable this is not a solution.

**2) tell the compiler that you are sure it's not null in this situation**

This is done by adding `!` at the end of the variable. In your example that would be:
`b.name!.compareTo(a.name!)`
This is probably the easiest solution but the program will throw errors at runtime if they do happen to be `null`

**3) provide a fallback value using `??`**

`??` basically is an operator that returns the left side if it's not `null` and otherwise the right side. You can use this to your advantage to provide fallback values. In your example you could do:
`(b.name ?? '').compareTo(a.name ?? '')`
This way it takes empty string in case the name is missing. This would be a safer option compared to option 2.

**4) conditional calling using `?.`**

Maybe not applicable in your situation but good to know anyway. Let's say some class `A` has the method `getName` and you have an object `a` of type `A?` and this code:

```
String? b = a.getName();
```

this is not allowed because `a` can be `null`. But you can write this:

```
String? b = a?.getName();
```

This basically mean that it executes `getName()` and assigns it to `b` when `a` is not `null` or just assigns `null` otherwise, which is possible because `b` is allowed to be `null` here. Therefore, this is NOT possible

```
String b = a?.getName();
```

Now `b` is defined as not being nullable and since the assignment possibly can provide `null` you are not allowed to.